# How to add color for android calendar events?

Tags: android, android-calendar

I want to add color for android calendar events, i have used the following code

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, phNumber);
values.put(Events.DISPLAY_COLOR, 0xffff0000);
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, "UTC");
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

But this code is not added color for event. Even i'm not able to add event in calendar when i use values.put(Events.DISPLAY_COLOR, 0xffff0000) code. How can i implement Events.DISPLAY_COLOR?

Comment: can you try `Color.parseColor("0xffff0000")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Events.EVENT_COLOR` instead of `Events.DISPLAY_COLOR`

As a reference, you can use this [link](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/androids-calendarcontract-provider/) to work with `Calendars`

Comment: Thanks Jitendar, Please note my updated code in my questions, thats also have the same pblm, even i'm not able to add event in calendar when i use values.put(Events.DISPLAY_COLOR, 0xffff0000);

Answer (score 0):

I reached the goal by:

```
event.put("eventColor", 0xffff0000);
```

Comment: so that is full alpha, full red, no green, no blue? FF FF 00 00.

Comment: the custom color changes back to default on click of the event