# Sync Google Calendar events to Custom calendar using android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, google-calendar-api

I manage to add events in google calendar and viewing the list of events but my problem is how can i sync those events to my custom calendar and the day must have a different color or any mark so that the user would know that the day has a event.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync) if this is the one you are looking for about syncing. Now, about the color of the events, you can set this different color in creating events by using the parameter [colorId](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#colorId). For more information, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523259) on how to do it in android code.

Comment: How can i connect the google calendar to my custom calendar?

Comment: I am newbie here in android studiosorry Thanks